# Integer variable for Set cannot be resolved as type

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I am creating an application to allow a user to assign a lane number for 8 racer's. I have set the runners names into an ArrayList and the lanes into a Set. At the moment I am calling the list and set into a Class Array. I will combine the ArrayList and Set as a Singleton Map.  I cannot get the Set to accept the Integer variable raceLane as a Type.  Any help with the Set problem and suggestions on how to turn the ArrayList and Set into a Singleton Map would be appreciated thank you.  Here is what I have so far.

```
package Race;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class LaneDesignation {



//create ArrayList and Set
private ArrayList runnersArray= new ArrayList();
private Set<raceLane> raceLanesSet = new HashSet<raceLane>();
//Declare Variables
private Integer raceLane;  
String runnerName;
int numbRunner, i = 0;
//Call Scanner Instance   
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public LaneDesignation()
{
    this.raceLane = raceLane;
}

public void setNumb(int numb)
{
    numbRunner= numb;
}   

public void setName()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of runner " + numbRunner + ": ");
    runnerName = input.next();
    i = 0;
    runnersArray.add(i, runnerName); 
    i++;     
}

public String returnName()
{
    return runnerName;
}


public void getLane()
{
    raceLanesSet.add(0, raceLane);

    do
    {

        System.out.print("Please enter the lane the runner is assigned to ");
        while (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            //Test that only numeric characters were entered
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.  Please enter a numeric value");
            System.out.print("Please enter a lane designation from 1-8: ");
            input.next();
        }

        raceLane = input.nextInt();

    }while (raceLane <=0);
    raceLanesSet.add(i, raceLane);

    i++; 
}

public Integer returnLane()
{
return raceLane;
}

public void displayDesignation()
{           
    System.out.println("Runner   |   Desinated Lane");
    while (i < runnersArray.size())
    {
        System.out.println(runnersArray.(i) + " will race in lane" +  raceLanesSet.get(i));
        i++;
    }
}

public void setRaceLane(Integer raceLane)
{
    this.raceLane = raceLane;
} 

}
```

The ArrayList and Set are called and combined as a ClassArray
    //Inspired by Kacey

```
package Race;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Runners {


   //creation array of classes of class LaneDesignation
   LaneDesignation[] Assign = new LaneDesignation[8];//8 Runners and 8 lanes
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public Runners()
    {
      //initialization of the class
      for (int i=0; i<Assign.length; i++){
         Assign[i] = new LaneDesignation();
    }
}

public void raceArray()
{
    for(int i=0;i<Assign.length; i++)
    {       
        Assign[i].setNumb((i+1));        

        Assign[i].setName(); 

        Assign[i].getLane();

     }
}
//Method to display the contents in the list
//I am receiving  runnersArray cannot be resolved to variable error
public void outputRunners() 
{
    for(LaneDesignation currentRunner : runnersArray)
    {
        System.out.println(currentRunner.getRunner());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Set<Integer> raceLanesSet = new HashSet<Integer>()`? Did you also mean `List<String> runnersArray = new ArrayList<String>()`?

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter of collections(set/HashSet/ArrayList...) should be of an Object type. 
raceLane is not an object type, it is just a variable of type Integer.
You have to change

```
Set<Integer> raceLanesSet = new HashSet<Integer>()
```

Either you have to define a new class "raceLane"

Comment: Sorry, Set<Integer> raceLanesSet = new HashSet<Integer>()

Comment: The Set is for an Integer type and the List is for string a string type.  Correcting the Type (removing the variable) in the set allowed me to create the Set but I lost the ability to keep track of which runner it belonged to with the numbRunner counter.  I want to use a set to restrict duplicate lane assignment.

Comment: I think for your problem you should change your data structure. Why don't you basically take a HahsMap? For example,  HashMap<Integer,String> = new HahsMap(), where the key can represent the unique number you want to assing to every runner and String could be a name ? Or if you need more complex data to keep for runnerns then define HashMap<Integer,Runner> = new HashMap(), where Runner has all data about each runner, and key again is the assigned line ? Do you have a specific requirement about data structure ?